# Can't create component as it has dependencies to be satisfied. Parameter which was not provided

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, castle-windsor, windsor-3.0

I have just started using Windsor to resolve dependency. But i am getting below error while passing string value in my Controller.I checked couple of similar Windsor Post but no luck.

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public readonly String _A = string.Empty;
    public HomeController(string A)
    {
        this._A = A;        
    }
}
```

Installer

```
public void Install(IWindsorContainer container, IConfigurationStore store)
    {
        container.Register(Classes.FromThisAssembly()
            .BasedOn<IController>()
            .LifestyleTransient());
    }
```

WindsorControllerFactory

```
public class WindsorControllerFactory : DefaultControllerFactory
    {
        private readonly IKernel kernel;

        public WindsorControllerFactory(IKernel kernel)
        {
            this.kernel = kernel;
        }

        public override void ReleaseController(IController controller)
        {
            kernel.ReleaseComponent(controller);
        }

        protected override IController GetControllerInstance(RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType)
        {
            if (controllerType == null)
            {
                throw new HttpException(404, string.Format("The controller for path '{0}' could not be found.", requestContext.HttpContext.Request.Path));
            }
            return (IController)kernel.Resolve(controllerType);
        }
    }
```

Do i need to wrap 'A' inside a class and resolve it's respective Interface ?

Answer (score 2):

Yes that would be the preferable solution as it makes the dependency very clear.

```
public class HomeControllerConfig
{
    public string A { get; set; }
}

public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public readonly String _A = string.Empty;
    public HomeController(HomeControllerConfig config)
    {
        this._A = config.A;        
    }
}
```

Installer

```
public void Install(IWindsorContainer container, IConfigurationStore store)
{
    ...
    container.Register(Component.For<HomeControllerConfig>().Instance(new HomeControllerConfig { A = "..." }));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what `A` really is, semantically for your application, but in short, no - you don't have to wrap it. [The documentation explains in detail](https://github.com/castleproject/Windsor/blob/master/docs/inline-dependencies.md) how to configure it.